# Save all value from Customized Listview (including EditText) into SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I expect to store data get from value of View on List view to SQLite and popular them on Listview when reopen app. I used this method on EditText

```
 ....setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {...
```

to save data on SQLite right after change EditText But Its doesn't work properly.
[image]
**Here is MyCustomAdapter Class**

```
  public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {
  private Context context;
  private int resource;
  private ArrayList<Song> listsong;
  private DatabaseHelper datab;
  private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
  public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Song> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context=context;
    this.resource=resource;
    this.listsong=objects;
}
@Override
public Song getItem(int position) {
    return listsong.get(position);
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    viewHolder=null;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.song_items,parent,false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.tenbai = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        viewHolder.delaytime = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delay);
        viewHolder.timeunit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timeunit);
        //attach the TextWatcher listener to the EditText


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        Log.d(TAG, "getView: "+(position+1));
        // SELETECTED

    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Song infor = listsong.get(position);
    viewHolder.tenbai.setText(infor.getTenbai());
    viewHolder.timeunit.setText(infor.getTimeunit());
    viewHolder.delaytime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


 //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
    viewHolder.delaytime.setText(infor.getDelaytime());
    viewHolder.delaytime.setId(position);

 //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
    viewHolder.delaytime.setOnFocusChangeListener(new 
 View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (!hasFocus) {
                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                listsong.get(position).setDelaytime(Caption.getText().toString());

                new DatabaseHelper(context).insertSong( listsong.get(position) );
            }

        }

    });

    return convertView;
}
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView tenbai;
    EditText delaytime;
    TextView timeunit;

}
}
```

**Here is DatabaseHelper Class**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "songs_db";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // create notes table
    db.execSQL(Song.CREATE_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Song.TABLE_NAME);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean ifExists(String tenbai)
{    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    String checkQuery = "SELECT " + Song.COLUMN_TENBAI + " FROM " + Song.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + Song.COLUMN_TENBAI + "= '"+tenbai + "'";
    cursor= db.rawQuery(checkQuery,null);
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
public boolean isEmpty(String TableName){

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int NoOfRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(database,TableName);

    if (NoOfRows == 0){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean isTableExists(String tableName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    boolean isExist = false;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '" + tableName + "'", null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            isExist = true;
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return isExist;
}

public void insertSong(Song song) {
    // get writable database as we want to write data
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Song.COLUMN_TENBAI, song.getTenbai());
    values.put(Song.COLUMN_DUONGDAN, song.getDuongdan());
    values.put(Song.COLUMN_DELAYTIME, song.getDelaytime());
    values.put(Song.COLUMN_TIMEUNIT, song.getTimeunit());
    // insert row
    long id = db.insert(Song.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    // close db connection
    db.close();
    Log.d("Ket qua", "addStudent Successfuly");
    // return newly inserted row id

}

// TAO MANG CHO RECYCLE QUAN NotesAdapter
public List<Song> getAllSongs() {
    List<Song> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Song.TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " +
            Song.COLUMN_TENBAI + " DESC";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Song song = new Song();
            song.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(song.COLUMN_ID)));
            song.setTenbai(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(song.COLUMN_TENBAI)));
            song.setDuongdan(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(song.COLUMN_DUONGDAN)));
            song.setDelaytime(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(song.COLUMN_DELAYTIME)));
            song.setTimeunit(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(song.COLUMN_TIMEUNIT)));

            notes.add(song);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // close db connection
    db.close();

    // return notes list
    return notes;
}


public int getNotesCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Song.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();


    // return count
    return count;
}
public int updatedelaytime(Song song) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Song.COLUMN_DELAYTIME, song.getDelaytime());
    // updating row
    return db.update(Song.TABLE_NAME, values, Song.COLUMN_TENBAI + " = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(song.getTenbai())});
}
```

**Here is MainActivity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton btnList,btnPlay,btnStop,btnForward,btnPrev;
Button btnsave;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private TextView txtTotal,txtCurrent;

 private SeekBar soundSeek;

int currentPosition = 0;
int totalDuration = 0;
int value  =0;
boolean Playing = false;
String audioFile = "";
int SONG_NUMBER = 0;
int CURRENT_NUMBER= 0;
private DatabaseHelper db;
private ListView playList;
MyCustomAdapter myCustomAdapter;
public static ArrayList<Song> fileNames;
public ArrayList<Song> newlistsong;

String INTERNAL_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() .toString()+"/";;
String EXTERNAL_PATH = "Download";

static String AUDIO_PATH = "";

String[] DIRECTORIES = {INTERNAL_PATH,EXTERNAL_PATH};
public static int songNumber ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );

    btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btnList = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imbList);
    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    btnStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    btnPrev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    txtCurrent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    txtTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    soundSeek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    playList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    playList.setItemsCanFocus( true );

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

 if(!db.isTableExists( "songs" )||db.isEmpty("songs")) {
     fileNames=new ArrayList<Song>(  );
     Collections.sort(fileNames, new Comparator<Song>() {
         @Override
         public int compare(Song data1, Song data2) {
     return (int) data1.getTenbai().charAt(0) - (int) data2.getTenbai().charAt(0);
         }

     });
     getFiles();
     playList.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter( this, R.layout.song_items, fileNames ) );
 }
 else
    {
        newlistsong =new ArrayList<Song>(  );
        Collections.sort(newlistsong, new Comparator<Song>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Song data1, Song data2) {
                return (int) data1.getTenbai().charAt(0) - (int) data2.getTenbai().charAt(0);
            }
        });
        newlistsong.addAll( db.getAllSongs() );
        playList.setAdapter( new MyCustomAdapter( this, R.layout.song_items, newlistsong ));
        System.out.println( "mang : " +newlistsong.size()+"phan tu: "+newlistsong.toString());
    }

    playList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, fileNames.get(position).getDuongdan().toString()+" vi tri "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            SONG_NUMBER=position;
           playMedia(fileNames.get(position).getDuongdan().toString());
        }
    });

    setListeners();
}



public void getFiles(){
    fileNames.clear();
    for(int d = 0 ; d < DIRECTORIES.length ; d++){
        File f = new File(DIRECTORIES[d]);
        f.mkdir();

        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if(files != null && files.length > 0){
            for(File file : files){
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    scanDirectory(file);
                }else{
                    addSong(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public void scanDirectory(File directory){
    if(directory != null){
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file:listFiles){
            // neu muon load tat ca cac file trong folder cha
            if(file.isDirectory()){
                scanDirectory(file);
            }else{
                addSong(file);
            }

        }

    }
}

    public void addSong(File song) {

    if (song.getName().endsWith( ".mp3" ) && song.getAbsolutePath().contains( EXTERNAL_PATH )) {
        fileNames.add( new Song( song.getName(), song.getAbsolutePath(), "", "sec" ) );
    }
}
    public static String getpath(String tenbai)
    { String path = null;
        for (int i=0;i<fileNames.size();i++)
        {
            if(fileNames.get(i).getTenbai().equals( tenbai ))
            {path= fileNames.get(i).getDuongdan();}
        }
        return path;
    }

public void save()
{
            DatabaseHelper dbhelp=  new DatabaseHelper(this);
    for(int i=0;i<fileNames.size();i++) {
        Song moderntalking= new Song();
        moderntalking.setTenbai( fileNames.get(i).getTenbai());
        moderntalking.setDuongdan( fileNames.get(i).getDuongdan());
        moderntalking.setDelaytime( fileNames.get(i).getDelaytime());
        moderntalking.setTimeunit( fileNames.get(i).getTimeunit());
        System.out.println( moderntalking.getDelaytime() );
        if(!dbhelp.ifExists( moderntalking.getTenbai() ))
        {  dbhelp.insertSong( fileNames.get(i) );}
        else
        {  dbhelp.updatedelaytime( moderntalking );}
    }

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

**Here is Song Class**
    public class Song {

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "songs";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String COLUMN_TENBAI = "tenbai";
public static final String COLUMN_DUONGDAN = "duongdan";
public static final String COLUMN_DELAYTIME = "delaytime";
public static final String COLUMN_TIMEUNIT = "timeunit";

    public  Integer id;
    public String tenbai;
    public String duongdan;
    public String delaytime;
    public String timeunit;

public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + COLUMN_TENBAI + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_DUONGDAN + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_DELAYTIME + " TEXT,"
                + COLUMN_TIMEUNIT + " TEXT"
                + ")";

public Song() {}
public Song( String tenbai, String duongdan, String delaytime, String timeunit) {
    this.tenbai = tenbai;
    this.duongdan = duongdan;
    this.delaytime = delaytime;
    this.timeunit = timeunit;
}
public Song(Integer id, String tenbai, String duongdan, String delaytime, String timeunit) {
    this.id = id;
    this.tenbai = tenbai;
    this.duongdan = duongdan;
    this.delaytime = delaytime;
    this.timeunit = timeunit;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTenbai() {
    return tenbai;
}

public void setTenbai(String tenbai) {
    this.tenbai = tenbai;
}

public String getDuongdan() {
    return duongdan;
}

public void setDuongdan(String duongdan) {
    this.duongdan = duongdan;
}

public String getDelaytime() {
    return delaytime;
}

public void setDelaytime(String delaytime) {
    this.delaytime = delaytime;
}

public String getTimeunit() {
    return timeunit;
}

public void setTimeunit(String timeunit) {
    this.timeunit = timeunit;
}
}
```

I want to store the String name, path, delaytime, timeunit in SQLite. Then get them to show on Customized Listview correctly. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Possibly depending on what the user actually does the focus might not change.

e.g.

When the user clicks on first `edittext` then the focus might already be on this.

And if the app closes the focus might still be on the first `edittext`

Thus no events are fired

Really there are two ways of correctly implementing this:-

1) Add a `TextWatcher` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html to the `edittext` so if the value is changed in the `edittext` the `TextWatcher` is fired and you save the value to the database.

Quote from `edittext` documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText

> You also can receive callbacks as a user changes text by adding a TextWatcher to the edit text. This is useful when you want to add auto-save functionality as changes are made, or validate the format of user input, for example. You add a text watcher using the TextView#addTextChangedListener method.

2) Handle the saving of the values to the database in the App's `onPause` method, so when the app is being closed or put in to the background then the code looks at all the listbox items and works out which ones need to be updated in the database.